# How to give a function a value from another function in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that solves a quadratic equation:

```
class QuadEq(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def solve_quad_eq(self):
        D = self.b**2-4*self.a*self.c
        if D >= 0:
            x1 = (-self.b-math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
            x2 = (-self.b+math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
            answer = [x1, x2]
            return answer
        else:
            return 0
```

And then in the same Class I have function:

```
 def show_result(self):
    print answer
```

that to print the answer of the quadratic equation if we need.

How can I give this function the ***answer*** *list* from the function above it to print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer has already been posted. Use an [instance variable](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) (`self.answer`):

```
class QuadEq(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def solve_quad_eq(self):
        self.answer = ("this", "that")
        return self.answer

    def show_result(self):
        print self.answer


eq = QuadEq(1,2,3)

eq.solve_quad_eq()
eq.show_result()
```

Loosely speaking, an instance variable (*data member*) is just a variable whom lifespan is the same as the one of its "owner" (in the example, the object referenced by `eq`).

---

And now, for the long -- and slightly more pedantic - answer: when designing a *class*, you have to think about its [responsibilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and its [state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29#Properties_of_an_object). Simply said, what is the purpose of your class? Is it just a *container* for various more-or-less related functions? In that case, the above answer is perfectly acceptable. But usually, you have to be a little bit more rigorous -- at the very least in order to improve understandability/maintainability of your code.

Here you have a `QuadEq` class. By its name, I understand an instance of this class models *one* equation. Since the roots of such an equation are a *properties* of that equation, I think it is acceptable to have the method `solve_quad_eq` to be a method of that class. With the slight change I would use the more generic name `solve`. Why? Because that make provision for future classes for different equations providing the same *semantic*. In addition, both returning the result *and* storing it in an instance variable might be confusing. You should make a choice here. Not mentioning the fact your function sometimes returns the roots, other time the number of roots (`0`).

Now, *printing*. I am more skeptical about this one. Displaying itself is not a "native" property of an equation. And if you go that way, you'll soon have to deal in your(s) equation class(es) with problems totally unrelated with "equations": how to write in a file? Binary or text? Which encoding should I use? How to deal with I/O errors? and so on...

So, if I were you, I would push toward [separation of concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), providing just an "accessor" method to return the roots -- and display them from the outside. Since this seems to be important, I keep here the separation between that accessor and the `solve` method (potentially computationally intensive for some kinds of equations). Using the instance variable `self.answer` merely as a cache ([memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization))

Here is a full example:

```
class Eq(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.answer = None # this should be calles "roots", no?

    def roots(self):
        if self.answer is None:
            self.solve()

        return self.answer

class QuadEq(Eq):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        Eq.__init__(self)

        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def solve(self):
        self.answer = ("this", "that")
        return 2

eq = QuadEq(1,2,3)
print(eq.roots())
```

Please note how easy it is now to add an other kind of equation to solve in the program ...

```
class OtherEq(Eq):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        Eq.__init__(self)

        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def solve(self):
        self.answer = ( "it", )
        return 1
```

... and more important, the code to use that new kind of equation is almost the same as the previous one:

```
eq = OtherEq(1,2,3)
print(eq.roots())
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the answer a member of the class. and reference it by `self.answer`.

```
class QuadEq(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.answer = []


    def solve_quad_eq(self):
        D = self.b**2-4*self.a*self.c
        if D >= 0:
            x1 = (-self.b-math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
            x2 = (-self.b+math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
            self.answer = [x1, x2]
            return self.answer
        else:
            return 0

    def show_result(self):
        print self.answer
```

Comment: If the solve function is not called, self.answer is an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in the object itself:

```
class QuadEq(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.solution = None

    def solve_quad_eq(self):
        if self.solution is None:
            D = self.b**2-4*self.a*self.c
            if D >= 0:
                x1 = (-self.b-math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
                x2 = (-self.b+math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
                self.solution = [x1, x2]
            else:
                self.solution = 0
        return self.solution

    def show_result(self): # <--- just an alias to solve_quad_eq
        return self.solve_quad_eq()
```

Comment: `return self.solve_quad_eq(self)` should probably be just `return self.solve_quad_eq()`

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an exception if the functions are run in the wrong order:

```
class QuadEq(object):
def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    self.answer = None

    #Rest of program...

def show_result(self):
    if self.answer is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Error in QuadEq, tried to print result before solving equation')
    print self.answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep `answer` as a member variable.

```
def solve_quad_eq(self):
    D = self.b**2-4*self.a*self.c
    if D >= 0:
        x1 = (-self.b-math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
        x2 = (-self.b+math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
        self.answer = [x1, x2]
        return self.answer
    else:
        return 0

def show_result(self):
    print self.answer
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really; unless you make answer a member of the class like this

```
class QuadEq(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def solve_quad_eq(self):
        D = self.b**2-4*self.a*self.c
        if D >= 0:
            x1 = (-self.b-math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
            x2 = (-self.b+math.sqrt(D))/2*self.a
            answer = [x1, x2]
            return answer
        else:
            return 0

    def show_result(self):
        if self.answer is None:
            self.answer =  solve_quad_eq()
        print self.answer
```

or do something simpler like this...

```
def show_result(self):
    print self.solve_quad_eq()
```